# Which gender for adjectives referred to multiple nouns of different genders?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gender

> 1. Sia i coperchi che le pentole sono rossi.
> 2. Sia i coperchi che le pentole sono rosse.

Con cosa dovrebbe concordare il colore delle pentole e dei coperchi?

> a. con pentole perché le pentole sono più grandi dei coperchi (1 is wrong);
>
> b. con coperchi perché il genere maschile prevale sul genere femminile (1 is right);
>
> c. con coperchi perché i coperchi stanno sopra le pentole (1 is right);
>
> d. con pentole perché le pentole precedono immediatamente prima l'aggettivo (1 is wrong).

Comment: Come ti sono venute in mente le risposte a. e c.??

Comment: @DaG, alcune volte i fattori psicologici influenzano l'uso delle parole, though.

Answer (score 11):

b. perché in italiano, come in molte altre lingue indoeuropee, il maschile è il genere “non marcato” (cioè quello usato anche in situazioni generiche, oltre che per denotare specificamente esseri di sesso maschile).

> Se i nomi sono di genere diverso, l'aggettivo assume il numero plurale e, di preferenza, il genere maschile; «tale preferenza» – fanno notare Dardano-Trifone [...] – «si spiega col valore più vicino al ‘neutro’ del maschile rispetto al femminile».

da *Italiano* di Serianni, Garzanti 1997, pag. 141 (che peraltro consiglio di tenere sempre sotto mano per tutti i dubbi linguistici).

Comment: aggiungo che addirittura "sia il coperchio che la pentola **sono rossi**", quindi passando al plurale.